# UK based, with US Contract. What is my tax situation?

Tags: contracts, taxes

I've been doing this for about a year, but it's usually been UK based companies and never US ones. I don't know the protocol here and don't want to get on the wrong side of the IRS, so is there anyone who has been in a similar situation who could please give me some advice?

Edit: Never set foot in the US, always been a resident of the UK

Comment: I do not believe you are affected by the IRS being you are in the UK. You do not work in the US. Thus, I believe you would be more affected by your local tax codes.